# need to Compare two folders recursively in hdfs and get copied missed files in to folder-2 from folder-1

Tags: shell, hdfs, hadoop2

I have two folders in hdfs, In folder-1 have some files and sub-folders, where as folder-2 contains the some of files and sub-folders of folder-1. 
Now i need to copy missing files and sub folders of folder-1 to folder-2.

and is this possible to do using shell script?

can any one help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

Use `distcp`.

```
$ hadoop distcp -update FOLDER1 FOLDER2
```

I would look at the examples in [DistCp Version2 Guide](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-distcp/DistCp.html) to make sure you're comfortable with the semantics of `-update`.